# Count number of words based on word length

Tags: php

I need a PHP function that will count how much words are with 1,2,3,4 etc letters in a text

The text is:

```
$lorem = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam mollis urna nisl, ut euismod purus adipiscing vitae. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ultricies risus non arcu bibendum tempor."
```

**For example:**

```
Number of words with 1 letter is: ....
Number of words with 2 letters is: ....
Number of words with 3 letters is: ....
```

etc

Comment: Have you got any example of code which you've tried to solve this problem yourself?

Comment: Do you expect us to do the work for you? Stack Overflow is **not** a code-writing service.

Comment: Hint: use ```strtok()``` (or a regex) and ```strlen()```.

Comment: Looks like a homework task you're asking us to solve for you...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$lorem = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam mollis urna nisl, ut euismod purus adipiscing vitae. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent ultricies risus non arcu bibendum tempor.";

$arr = explode(" ",$lorem);

$arr_count = array();
foreach($arr as $val)
{
    $key = strlen($val);
    if(isset($arr_count[$key]))
    {
        $arr_count[$key]+=1;
    }   
    else
    {
        $arr_count[$key] =1;    
    }
}
ksort($arr_count);
foreach($arr_count as $key=>$val)
{
    echo "Number of words with ".$key." letter is:".$val."<br/>";
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Number of words with 2 letter is:1
Number of words with 3 letter is:4
Number of words with 4 letter is:2
Number of words with 5 letter is:13
Number of words with 6 letter is:2
Number of words with 7 letter is:2
Number of words with 8 letter is:2
Number of words with 9 letter is:1
Number of words with 10 letter is:3
Number of words with 11 letter is:2
```

See **[DEMO](http://codepad.org/k2WC4VJU)**

Comment: "amet," is not a word.

Comment: this is combined that why getting the word. whereas you can use some php function for it like `str_replace(",", "", $val)`

Comment: now put some efforts from your side also which help you to build your own logics.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
foreach(explode(' ',$lorem) as $word)
    $arr[strlen($word)] = isset($arr[strlen($word)]?$arr[strlen($word)]+1:1);
```

Now `$arr` is an array. The keys of the array are the number of letters. The values of the array are the corresponding number of words.